# Android App with different Home

Tags: android, mysql, authentication

I'm writing an Android App to organize some group chats. 
User have to login with an username & a password to use this app. After that, a user can join a group chat and can chat with other users in this chat or he has the opportunity to create new groups or join an existing group.

So a user who is a member of a group got a startscreen with buttons like "Chat" or "Leave group", and a user who isn't a member of a group got buttons like "Join group" or "Create group"

Now, here's my problem. How can I manage different startscreens for each user-group (member of a group or not).

I thought about label each user in my database, if he is a group member or not, and check it on my MainActivity, before i set the ContentView like:

//MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    ...
    if(user.member_of_group)
       setContentView(R.layout.member_layout);
    else
       setContentView(R.layout.no_member_layout);
}
```

Would that makes sense? Or is there a better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.it makes sense.This is a common solution for this kind of problems.A good example is **session management** in android.It checks the state of a user and then decide to launch proper layout.You can do this by labeling users with groups.